# symfony2 + doctrine2: map many entity to join to the same entity composite primary key

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, key, composite

I need to map many entities as one to many to the same entity primary key.

For the sake of brevity i will try to semplify a little bit:

Suppose I have a news and a product table that need to be ordered differently if shown on the website or in the ios app. I would like to have only one table that store the order informations (called "position") for all the tables because in future i will need to manage other 20 tables or more.

Here are the simplified tables:

```
 _________
|news     |
 ---------
|id (pk)  |
|title    |
 ---------

 _________
|product  |
 ---------
|id (pk)  |
|name     |
 ---------

 __________
|position  | id + table + target are the composite primary key
 ----------
|id (pk)   | can refer to a news.id or to a product.id depending on table field value
|table(pk) | define if the id refer to a news or to a product
|target(pk)| can be "web" or "ios"
|position  | an integer  
 ----------

3 possible position records could be:

id  - table  - position - target
1      news        1        web
1      news        1        ios
1      product     1        web
```

As you can see I can have the same id repeated 3 times.
I know this is a little bit dirty and maybe is not a best practice but it will save me a lot of table and entity creation every time I need to add a table (press, artists, events, etc).
The only way I know to use Doctrine2 to fit my needs is to create a xxx_position_web and a xxx_position_ios table and the related entities for every new table i will have to manage in the future.

Is it possible to manage something like this with Doctrine2 entities in Symfony2.
I found a link that explain a situation quite similar to mine https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html?highlight=composite#identity-through-foreign-entities but I'm not able to apply it to my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Class Table Inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance) in the docs.

You can use *position* as super-table with *news* and *product* being discriminators (i.e. what you do with the table-field). Now you only have to add target as a composite key on your mapped superclass (position).

Whenever you add a new table, like *press* or *event* you just have to add them to the discriminator map and create a new model with the additional fields.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answer, Class Table Inheritance seems very interesting.

Using it I will have something like

```
/** @Entity */
class News extend Position
{
...
}
```

And what about if in my situation I need a relation to position and also to another table with the same structure (unfortunately this is my case, I need to manage also a visibility table).
I can't make news extends both position and Visibility.